# Basic Understanding - TypeScript and HowTo properly implement JS-Modules into Webproject

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, implementation

I am struggeling with the current situation. Up to today i had my own JavaScript implementation with own methods to load single js files per website - when needed. This way i had a tiny loader script with an scp sha256-checksum in the header which then loaded the "master" script which controlled everything else.
Now i want to go some steps further and a) switch over to modules, because most libs do so too, i was unable to load modules from normal scripts and b) implement typescript into my system.

What starts my script implementation:

```
/scripts/modules-loader.js
<html>
    ...
    <script async type=module>
        "use strict";
        import {master} from '/scripts/modules/master-28021723540.js';
        new master();
    </script>
    ...
</html>
```

So far so good. This loader executes as expected, the js file is been loaded and the sha-256 hash from the header is valid.

And now where the struggle begins. This file is been compiled to

```
/master.ts
export class master {
    constructor() {
        this.init();
    }

    async init() {
        console.log( "Hello, lets get started...");
    }
}
```

compiled file:

```
define("wkwussmxlyk4d7ainbsq93pnpnugjs5g", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    exports.master = void 0;
    class master {
        constructor() {
            this.init();
        }
        async init() {
            console.log("Hello, lets get started...");
        }
    }
    exports.master = master;
});
```

with the result that the browser cannot find the module called "master"

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/scripts/modules/master-28021723540.js' 
does not provide an export named 'master' (at (Index):11:9)
```

However i also tried this, which i found in the internet:

```
"use strict";
module master {
    class master {
        constructor() {
            this.init();
        }

        async init() {
            console.log( "Hello, lets get started...");
        }
    }
}
```

which gets compiled into this

```
"use strict";
var master;
(function (master_1) {
    class master {
        constructor() {
            this.init();
        }
        async init() {
            console.log("Hello, lets get started...");
        }
    }
})(master || (master = {}));
```

which leads to the same result.
How can i get my class get compiled from ts to be able to call it from the loader or in the file itself?

Just for understanding, i dont want to use the "tsc --watch" over my entire project. I am using single js/ts files and compile/optimize them in the request thread and put them into static optimized files afterwards ( if in production ). Keeping this in mind i am also open into different implementations. I am aiming for maximum pagespeed without compromises and my current solution was working very good but just limited because it was unable to load modules, so now i want to switch over to modules only.

i am compiling like this

```
/usr/bin/tsc --alwaysStrict --strict --module amd --target es2020 /srv/http/domain.local/tmp/domain.local/ncumh5cnk5uq2s7b64oa31cv19agr2s9.ts --outfile /srv/http/domain.local/tmp/domain.local/compiled-ncumh5cnk5uq2s7b64oa31cv19agr2s9.ts
```

Thanks in advance

Response on answer from @Quentin

```
/usr/bin/tsc --alwaysStrict --strict --target es6 /srv/http/domain.local/tmp/domain.local/ncumh5cnk5uq2s7b64oa31cv19agr2s9.ts --outfile /srv/http/domain.local/tmp/domain.local/compiled-ncumh5cnk5uq2s7b64oa31cv19agr2s9.ts
```

i am getting this compilation

```
"use strict";
var __awaiter = (this && this.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
    function adopt(value) { return value instanceof P ? value : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(value); }); }
    return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
        function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function rejected(value) { try { step(generator["throw"](value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function step(result) { result.done ? resolve(result.value) : adopt(result.value).then(fulfilled, rejected); }
        step((generator = generator.apply(thisArg, _arguments || [])).next());
    });
};
class master {
    constructor() {
        this.init();
    }
    init() {
        return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
            console.log("Hello, lets get started...");
        });
    }
}
```

and with

```
export class()
```

i am getting this:

```
Cannot compile modules using option 'outFile' unless the '--module' flag is 'amd' or 'system'.
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> --module amd
> ```

[This is your problem](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#module).

AMD modules use the `define` syntax and do no have native support in browsers. To use them you’ll need to use something like Require.JS.

Instead, tell TypeScript to generate an `es6` module.

Comment: thanks, i edited the above, but still not getting there. my compilation looks way different, but i still cannot access "master" and as soon as i write an export in front of the class declaration i am getting an error message "cannot compile modules". Can you please be a bit more detailed? thank you!

Comment: @SaschaGrindau I'm not sure that [--outFile](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#outFile) is doing what you're expecting it to do. It cannot be used to bundle ES Modules; it instead concatenates all non-module files (or System or AMD modules, if configured) into a single file.